# Editing a question placed on hold when I've already answered the question

Tags: discussion

The question to which I am referring is:  [Was the destruction of Herods temple in the first century a good thing or a bad thing?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59629/was-the-destruction-of-herods-temple-in-the-first-century-a-good-thing-or-a-bad)"

Now, this question was placed on hold due to it being opinion-based which I absolutely agree with. However, I do find it to be an interesting question and one worthy of analyzing on this site. I want to try and edit it within a way that would place it within the site guidelines. The problem is that I've already answered the question, and don't want to bias my editing of it to fit my answer.  The user who posted the question seems to have posted it and most likely won't return to edit it in a way that complies with site guidelines. Any suggestions on where I can go from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such a situation, the best course of action is to write your own on-topic question and then move your answer across (or as much of it that would apply to the new question.)